# visual basic console application error: data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: visual-studio, odbc

I had a working visual basic console application on windows 2000 that read a local Microsoft SQL database and did inserts into a remote MySQL database using Microsoft.Data.Odbc.
Then I upgraded to Windows 7 and now I get data source not found.
When I try to install Microsoft.Data.Odbc based on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310985  the link is broken to the ODBC .NET MANAGED PROVIDER.
So I tried to use System.Data.Odbc but I get the same error.
How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ODBC driver

this is the link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: I had installed it before asking question.